# ejabberd, XMPP showing a number after the username

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have set up ejabberd now the problem is.. (look at the screenshot). Users complaining about it it confuse them.

How can we hide the number?[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That part is called the *resource*, and uniquely identifies an particular session.  If you log in from more than one place at the same time, that part will distinguish them.

It will most likely won't be shown if you set a nickname for the contact in your roster.